# nodejs mysql how to close connection after a loop entered data into db

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, aws-cli

I have a fairly simple program which collect data from aws using aws-cli and nodejs and then enter it into MySQL. To be fair it does work, the only thing is that I would like this program to be scheduled to run every now and then but I cannot as it does not exit : when all data have been entered I do not end the connection. I tried to figure out how to do just that (close/end the connection to MySQL) with promises and async/await without success. Surely something I am not doing right (find it hard to grasp the concept of promises and asynchronous programing so far) but did try for days on end though.

```
[...]

    function insertInstanceDetails(date, zone, instance_id, name){
        let insert_details = "INSERT INTO instances (date, zone, instance_type, name) VALUES(" + db.escape(date) + "," + db.escape(zone) + "," + db.escape(instance_id) + "," + db.escape(name) + ")";
        db.query(insert_details, function(err, result){
            if(err) throw err;
        });
        return;
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                            

    for(instance-id of instance-ids){

        aws.command('ec2 describe-instaces .....').then(function (data) {
            var result = JSON.parse(data.raw); 

            for (var key in result.xyz) { 
                insertInstanceDetails(.......);
            }   
        });
    }
```

Thanks for helping. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One way of keeping track of whether the function `insertInstanceDetails` done executing is to convert it into a promise as well.

```js
function insertInstanceDetails(date, zone, instance_id, name) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let insert_details = "INSERT INTO instances (date, zone, instance_type, name) VALUES(" + db.escape(date) + "," + db.escape(zone) + "," + db.escape(instance_id) + "," + db.escape(name) + ")";
    db.query(insert_details, function(err, result) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
    });
    return resolve(result);
  });
}
```

And as for the `for..of` loop, it will act as the promise handler, and once it knows all the SQL job is done, it will close out the SQL connection as soon as possible

```js
for (instance - id of instance - ids) {

  aws.command('ec2 describe-instaces .....').then(function(data) {
    var result = JSON.parse(data.raw);
    const insertInserteDetailsJobs = [];
    for (var key in result.xyz) {
      insertInstanceDetailsJobs.push(insertInstanceDetails(.......));
    }
    // Handle, and watch over all those micro-promise
    return Promise.all(insertInstanceDetailsJobs);
  })
  .then(sqlResults => {
    // Now we know all the insert details has beeing successfully inseted into your DB
    // We can now close the SQL connection safely
    ...
    myDB.close();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Something fail
    console.error(err);
  });
}
```

Comment: you could actually simplify this using `Util.promisify` (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

Comment: Got sidetracked and then Covid19 took a hold. But thanks for the help Felix. I did try your code and it does work beautifully. Doesn't solve my issue though as the the DB gets filled in but connection does not get closed.